# Intentionally making ourselves remember things that never happened

Tags: memory, long-term-memory, visualization

I've been reading an interesting book  which makes mostly founded claims. However, there is no reference to any studies in regards to one of the following claims: according to the author, visualizing something that never happened every day for 3 weeks results in a memory which seems as real as any memory of something that did happen

Let's not focus on the 3 weeks statement. The interesting part is the claim that we can actually create memories which are as good as real. I am well aware that our memory is terrible. I've read around about various ways in which our memories can be changed: phrasing questions in a certain way, basing some false information on real information, priming etc.

But can we *really* make something that behaves just like a real memory, even if we are well aware that in reality, it's just a scenario that we imagined and repeated in our minds multiple times?

Answer (score 7):

If I understood correctly, you are talking about "false memories" in the context of the following definition in [(Johnson, M. K., 2001)](http://memlab.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/2001_Johnson_FalseMemories.pdf)

> "A false memory is a mental experience that is mistakenly taken to be
>   a veridical representation of an event from one's personal past.
>   Memories can be false in relatively minor ways (e.g., believing one
>   last saw the keys in the kitchen when they were in the living room)
>   and in major ways that have profound implications for oneself and
>   others (e.g., mistakenly believing one is the originator of an idea or
>   that one was sexually abused as a child)."

From  [Scientific American,
September 1997, Vol. 277 # 3,
pages 70-75](https://webfiles.uci.edu/eloftus/Loftus_ScientificAmerican_Good97.pdf)

This is a an article from 1997 by Elizabeth Loftus that may shed light on your question.
Yes, the information may be outdated and recent research might have expanded on it. **In that case, I might edit my answer soon to reflect those updates after completing further readings relating to the topic**

If recent developments interest you, in a study published in the journal *Science*, [Tonegawa et. al](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/341/6144/387) [associated with RIKEN-MIT Center for Neural Circuit Genetics] manipulated individual neurons to manipulate encoded memories in the brains of mice. [Read here.](http://www.theguardian.com/science/2013/jul/25/false-memory-implanted-mouse-brain)

**Misinformation Effect**

> My own research into memory distortion goes back to the early 1970s,
>   when I began studies of the "misinformation effect." These studies
>   show that when people who witness an event are later exposed to new
>   and misleading information about it, their recollections often become
>   distorted. In one example, participants viewed a simulated automobile
>   accident at an intersection with a stop sign. After the viewing, half
>   the participants received a suggestion that the traffic sign was a
>   yield sign. When asked later what traffic sign they remembered seeing
>   at the intersection, those who had been given the suggestion tended to
>   claim that they had seen a yield sign. Those who had not received the
>   phony information were much more accurate in their recollection of the
>   traffic sign.
>
> My students and I have now conducted more than 200 experiments
>   involving over 20,000 individuals that document how exposure to
>   misinformation induces memory distortion. In these studies, people
>   "recalled" a conspicuous barn in a bucolic scene that contained no
>   buildings at all, broken glass and tape recorders that were not in the
>   scenes they viewed, a white instead of a blue vehicle in a crime
>   scene, and Minnie Mouse when they actually saw Mickey Mouse. Taken
>   together, these studies show that misinformation can change an
>   individual's recollection in predictable and sometimes very powerful
>   ways.

**False Childhood Memories**

> My research associate, Jacqueline E. Pickrell, and I settled on trying
>   to plant a specific memory of being lost in a shopping mall or large
>   department store at about the age of five. Here's how we did it. We
>   asked our subjects, 24 individuals ranging in age from 18 to 53, to
>   try to remember childhood events that had been recounted to us by a
>   parent, an older sibling or another close relative. We prepared a
>   booklet for each participant containing one-paragraph stories about
>   three events that had actually happened to him or her and one that had
>   not. We constructed the false event using information about a
>   plausible shopping trip provided by a relative, who also verified that
>   the participant had not in fact been lost at about the age of five.
>   The lost-in-the-mall scenario included the following elements: lost
>   for an extended period, crying, aid and comfort by an elderly woman
>   and, finally, reunion with the family.
>
> [image: False Childhood Memories]
>
> After reading each story in the booklet, the participants wrote what
>   they remembered about the event. If they did not remember it, they
>   were instructed to write, "I do not remember this." In two follow-up
>   interviews, we told the participants that we were interested in
>   examining how much detail they could remember and how their memories
>   compared with those of their relative. The event paragraphs were not
>   read to them verbatim, but rather parts were provided as retrieval
>   cues. The participants recalled something about 49 of the 72 true
>   events (68 percent) immediately after the initial reading of the
>   booklet and also in each of the two follow-up interviews. After
>   reading the booklet, seven of the 24 participants (29 percent)
>   remembered either partially or fully the false event constructed for
>   them, and in the two follow-up interviews six participants (25
>   percent) continued to claim that they remembered the fictitious event.
>   Statistically, there were some differences between the true memories
>   and the false ones: participants used more words to describe the true
>   memories, and they rated the true memories as being somewhat more
>   clear. But if an onlooker were to observe many of our participants
>   describe an event, it would be difficult indeed to tell whether the
>   account was of a true or a false memory. Of course, being lost,
>   however frightening, is not the same as being abused. But the
>   lost-in-the-mall study is not about real experiences of being lost; it
>   is about planting false memories of being lost. The paradigm shows a
>   way of instilling false memories and takes a step toward allowing us
>   to understand how this might happen in real-world settings. Moreover,
>   the study provides evidence that people can be led to remember their
>   past in different ways, and they can even be coaxed into "remembering"
>   entire events that never happened.

**Imagination Inflation**

> What happens when people imagine childhood experiences that did not
>   happen to them? Does imagining a childhood event increase confidence
>   that it occurred? To explore this, we designed a three-stage
>   procedure. We first asked individuals to indicate the likelihood that
>   certain events happened to them during their childhood. The list
>   contains 40 events, each rated on a scale ranging from "definitely did
>   not happen" to "definitely did happen." Two weeks later we asked the
>   participants to imagine that they had experienced some of these
>   events. Different subjects were asked to imagine different events.
>   Sometime later the participants again were asked to respond to the
>   original list of 40 childhood events, indicating how likely it was
>   that these events actually happened to them. Consider one of the
>   imagination exercises. Participants are told to imagine playing inside
>   at home after school, hearing a strange noise outside, running toward
>   the window, tripping, falling, reaching out and breaking the window
>   with their hand. In addition, we asked participants questions such as
>   "What did you trip on? How did you feel?" In one study 24 percent of
>   the participants who imagined the broken-window scenario later
>   reported an increase in confidence that the event had occurred,
>   whereas only 12 percent of those who were not asked to imagine the
>   incident reported an increase in the likelihood that it had taken
>   place. We found this "imagination inflation" effect in each of the
>   eight events that participants were asked to imagine. A number of
>   possible explanations come to mind. An obvious one is that an act of
>   imagination simply makes the event seem more familiar and that
>   familiarity is mistakenly related to childhood memories rather than to
>   the act of imagination. Such source confusion when a person does not
>   remember the source of information can be especially acute for the
>   distant experiences of childhood.

**Impossible Memories**

> A procedure for planting "impossible" memories about experiences that
>   occur shortly after birth has been developed by the late Nicholas
>   Spanos and his collaborators at Carleton University. Individuals are
>   led to believe that they have well-coordinated eye movements and
>   visual exploration skills probably because they were born in hospitals
>   that hung swinging, colored mobiles over infant cribs. To confirm
>   whether they had such an experience, half the participants are
>   hypnotized, age-regressed to the day after birth and asked what they
>   remembered. The other half of the group participates in a "guided
>   mnemonic restructuring" procedure that uses age regression as well as
>   active encouragement to re-create the infant experiences by imagining
>   them.. Spanos and his co-workers found that the vast majority of their
>   subjects were susceptible to these memory-planting procedures. Both
>   the hypnotic and guided participants reported infant memories.
>   Surprisingly, the guided group did so somewhat more (95 versus 70
>   percent). Both groups remembered the colored mobile at a relatively
>   high rate (56 percent of the guided group and 46 percent of the
>   hypnotic subjects). Many participants who did not remember the mobile
>   did recall other things, such as doctors, nurses, bright lights, cribs
>   and masks. Also, in both groups, of those who reported memories of
>   infancy, 49 percent felt that they were real memories, as opposed to
>   16 percent who claimed that they were merely fantasies. These findings
>   confirm earlier studies that many individuals can be led to construct
>   complex, vivid and detailed false memories via a rather simple
>   procedure. Hypnosis clearly is not necessary.

---

**Sources:**

[The formation of false memories.](https://webfiles.uci.edu/eloftus/Loftus_Pickrell_PA_95.pdf) 
Loftus, E. F. & Pickrell, J. E. (1995). 
*Psychiatric Annals*, 25, 720-725.

[Imagination Inflation: Imagining A Childhood Event Inflates Confidence That It Occurred](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24213869). 
Maryanne Carry, Charles G. Manning, Elizabeth F. Loftus and Steven J. Sherman 
 *Psychonomic Bulletin and Review*, Vol. 3, No. 2, pages 208-214; June 1996.

[Remembering Our Past: Studies In Autobiographical Memory.](https://books.google.com/books?id=jwxVKrn6u9cC&dq=remembering%20our%20past%20rubin&source=gbs_navlinks_s) 
Edited by David C. Rubin. 
*Cambridge University Press*, 1996.

---

**Additional Reading:**

[Crisis or Creation: A systematic examination of false memory claims](http://www.leadershipcouncil.org/1/res/dallam/6.html). 
 Dallam, S. (2002). 
*Journal of Child Sexual Abuse* 9 (3/4): 9–36.

[False Memories Affect Behavior.](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/08/080819160245.htm) 
*Association for Psychological Science*  (2008, August 20).

---

Comment: Thank you. This is not exactly what I meant, but interesting nonetheless :) It seems (not surprisingly) that there isn't much (if at all) research about intentionally manipulating your own memories. However, It seems like you answered a question I had planned to post as a follow-up

Comment: Well, the book I've read actually suggests this as a way to overcome trauma by changing the memory, but the claim was about *creating* memories, which is also interesting, and might be useful. Though I have come to realize that even seemingly good thoughts/memories have serious implications which aren't always intuitive (for example, perfectionism often leads to procrastination)

Comment: It's called "Five gifts to the mind". I don't think the name (or any information about the book other than it's actual content) will be of much help. Either way, I think I've made my point clear - intentionally and knowingly creating false memories in yourself.